# Sharing html in facebook

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, html, ipad

In my iPad app i am loading HTML5 pages, i want to share these pages to Facebook. Is it possible?  i have searched a lot but could not find any help. My app should support iOS5 or later. Any help be grateful.

i am using below to share an image .

```
    FbGraphFile *graph_file = [[FbGraphFile alloc] initWithImage:picture];
    [variables setObject:graph_file forKey:@"file"];
    [variables setObject:@" image : Shared Via IOS application" forKey:@"message"];
    FbGraphResponse *fb_graph_response = [fbGraph doGraphPost:@"117795728310/photos" withPostVars:variables];
```

Comment: Please clarify your question. Facebook allows a HTML link or a media to be shared. what is the format of your `HTML5 pages`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue, `solution` is to `render HTML5 pages` in `UIWebView` and when it loads `capture image` from it and then `share`.

```
+(UIImage *)imageFromWebView:(UIWebView *)view
{
  // tempframe to reset view size after image was created
  CGRect tmpFrame         = view.frame;

  // set new Frame
  CGRect aFrame               = view.frame;
  aFrame.size.height  = [view sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size].height;
  view.frame              = aFrame;

  // do image magic
  UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([view sizeThatFits:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size]);

  CGContextRef resizedContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
  [view.layer renderInContext:resizedContext];
  UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

  // reset Frame of view to origin
  view.frame = tmpFrame;
  return image;
}
```